# How to add child control to Grid in specific position in code?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Suppose I define a Grid in xaml like:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>       
    </Grid>
```

then I want to add child control to the grid in column=0, row = 1 in code behind.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a late response but here you go:

```
Grid.SetRow(yourControl, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(yourControl, 1);

Grid.SetRow(otherControl, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(otherControl, 0);
```

The first parameter is the control you've added to your grid. The second parameter is the column/row position you want to add it to.